# How to find input layers names for intermediate layer in PyTorch model?

Tags: python, pytorch, layer

I have some complicated model on PyTorch. How can I print names of layers (or IDs) which connected to layer's input. For start I want to find it for Concat layer. See example code below:

```
class Concat(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dimension=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.d = dimension

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.cat(x, self.d)


class SomeModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SomeModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        self.conc = Concat(1)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(8192, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        out1 = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out2 = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        out = self.conc([out1, out2])
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 4)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = SomeModel()
    print(model)
    y = model(torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32))
    print(y.size())
    for name, m in model.named_modules():
        if 'Concat' in m.__class__.__name__:
            print(name, m, m.__class__.__name__)
            # Here print names of all input layers for Concat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `type(module).__name__` to get the `nn.Module` class name:

```
>>> model = SomeModel()
>>> y = model(torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32))
>>> for name, m in model.named_modules():
...     if 'Concat' == type(m).__name__:
...         print(name, m)
conc Concat()
```

---

*Edit*: You can actually manage to get the list of operators used to compute the inputs of `Concat`. However, I don't think you can actually get the attribute names of the `nn.Module` associated with these operators. This kind of information is not available - and needed - at model inference.

This solution requires you to register a forward hook on the layer with [`nn.Module.register_forward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_forward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook). Then perform one inference to trigger it, then you can remove the hook. In the forward hook, you have access to the list of inputs and extract the name of the operator from the `grad_fn` attribute callback. Using `nn.Module.register_forward_pre_hook` here would be more appropriate since we are only looking at the inputs, and do not need the output.

```
>>> def op_name(x)
...     return type(x.grad_fn).__name__.replace('Backward0', '')

>>> def forward_hook(module, ins):
...     print([op_name(x) for x in ins[0]])
```

Attach the hook on `model.conc`, trigger it and then clean up:

```
>>> handle = model.conc.register_forward_pre_hook(forward_hook)
>>> model(torch.empty(2, 3, 10, 10, requires_grad=True))
['Relu', 'Relu']

>>> handle.remove()
```

Comment: I need name of inputs for this layer. I know how to print name of current layer.

Comment: @ZFTurbo What do you mean by "name"? What would be the expected output in your example?

Comment: Example: ['module.conv1', 'module.conv2']

Comment: @ZFTurbo why is the expected result not `['module.bn1', 'module.conv2']`, since `bn1` is applied after `conv1` before being passed to `Concat`? Do you want to return the previous *closests* conv2d layer that were used on each input of `Concat`?

Comment: You are right about bn1. Actually I want to somehow print something which allows me to identify what is input of Concat module. The best option: ['module.conv1.bn1.relu', 'module.conv2.relu']

Comment: @ZFTurbo, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, currently it looks like most close answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I print names of layers (or IDs) which connected to layer's input.

You can't do it based on a module itself, because "connected to" doesn't exist as a static property of a `nn.Module`:

Instead of

```
out = self.conc([out1, out2])
```

you could just as easily have written

```
out = self.conc([out1, random.choice([out1, out2]))
```

What's connected to `self.conc` now?

However, you can inspect the "graph" of a *value* (If `torchviz.make_dot` doesn't directly do what you want, you may want to check its implementation)